# How to check latest restart processes in unix?

Tags: shell-script, awk, process

I am checking processes by "p" command and output is like below.

```
UID         PID   PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD                                    
myapp    10235  20365 99 Feb15 ?        11-15:01:41 cont AppRating  
myapp    20168  20365 99 01:39 ?        18:29:08 cont AppRating     
myapp    20322      1  0  2017 ?        18:07:14 monitor -p -a                          
myapp    20355  20322  0  2017 ?        12:34:55 agent -n                              
myapp    20780  20322 10  2017 ?        12-02:36:07 bsus -n                            
myapp    40675  20365 99 Feb16 ?        10-10:34:21 cont AppRating  
myapp    60749  20365 99 Feb21 ?        1-22:12:18 cont AppRating    
myapp   143363  20365  4 Feb26 ?        08:04:12 cont TimeOutSession    
myapp   143569  20365  1 Jan31 ?        05:57:05 cont AMn               
myapp   242818  20365 99 Feb21 ?        1-00:00:38 cont AppRating
```

Now i want to check the processes whose STIME is after day before yesterday.
suppose if today date is 27th feb 2018. then i want to check whether any process started after 26th feb 2018 00:00 AM.
if yes then print not ok infront of that line. like below output.

```
myapp    20168  20365 99 01:39 ?        18:29:08 cont AppRating --> NOTOK  
myapp   143363  20365  4 Feb26 ?        08:04:12 cont TimeOutSession --> NOTOK
```

Otherwise print simply "OK" only.

Answer (score 1):

Your `p` command seems to produce the same kind of output as `ps -Af`, it might be an alias.

The STIME in there is in the HH:MM format for processes started today, MonDD for processes started before today, YYYY for processes started last year or before, so to report processes that were started yesterday or today and assuming today is not the first of January, you could just look for entries where the STIME is the MonDD of yesterday or is in the HH:MM format.

Here assuming the GNU implementation of `date`:

```
p | awk -v yesterday="$(LC_ALL=C date -d yesterday +%b%d)" '
  NR > 1 {$0 = $0 " --> " ($5 == yesterday || $5 ~ /:/ ? "NOTOK" : "OK")}
  {print}'
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach that I can think of is choosing the output in seconds from the start.

```
ps -eo etimes,pid,cmd
```

This will give a list with the seconds since the start of the process, like this:

```
ELAPSED   PID CMD
  13802 26157 /just/some/command
```

The result can be used to extract the data. As I couldn't understand which logic you wanted to apply (something about two days ago), I just output the information and you can adjust the script to your needs. `172800` is 2 * 86400, which are the number of seconds in a day.

```
#!/bin/bash
ps -eo etimes,pid,cmd | grep -v ^ELAPSED | while read line
do
  ETIME=$(echo ${line} | awk '{ print $1 }')
  if [[ ${ETIME} -gt 172800]]; then
    echo "Old process ${line}"
  else
    echo "Newer process ${line}"
  fi
done
```

Comment: when i running this command it's giving me error like below:            
    ERROR: Unknown user-defined format specifier "etimes".

Comment: Which operation system are you using? I was testing on linux, especially Ubuntu.

Comment: i am using suse linux.

Comment: According to [this man page](https://www.unix.com/man-page/suse/1P/ps/), you might try `etime`. The trouble is that the output will be in the form `[[dd-]hh:]mm:ss`. So you'll have to re-calculate the output. This will still be possible as only numbers are involved, rather than dates with names of month written out.

Comment: dear stefan, by this command i  am not getting application specific user processes. it's giving the all the processes whether it's related to user or not.

Comment: Read the linked man page. `-u  userlist`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose if you want to check Process started 1 day earlier we can follow below steps

```
capturing_date=$(date +%b%d -d "1 days ago")


ps -eaf |awk -v k="$capturing_date" '$5 == k {print $0"============================>  Not OK"}'
```

Variable capturing_date ===> Captures the date one day earlier

```
ps -eaf |awk -v k="$capturing_date" '$5 == k {print $0"============================>  Not OK"}'   =================> it will  check for process which started 1 day earlier by evaluating in column 5
```